# JPA joined inheritance where base class can be both subtypes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Using Hibernate as the JPA implementation, I have the following model (simplified for this question) :

```
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Organisation {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  //Other general information about an org.
}

@Entity
@Table
public class ResearchInstitution extends Organisation {
  //Details on the research facet of the organisation
}

@Entity
@Table
public class FundingOrganisation extends Organisation {
  //Details on the funding facet of the organisation
}
```

An Organisation can be either or BOTH of the subtypes, which leads to the following problem when I query entities that refer to both facets of the same organisation. For example a Project (very simplified for this example) will have a List of participating ResearchInstitutions as well as a List of Fundings, each owned by a FundingOrganisation - simplified to a FundingOrganisation List for brevity in the following.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Project {
  private String title;

  private List <ResearchInstitution> participatingInstitutions;

  private List <FundingOrganisation> fundingOrganisations;
  //Lots of other properties
}
```

If the Project has the same Organisation being a ParticipatingInstitution (ResearchInstitution) and being a FundingOrganisation, (which is a valid usecase - institutions fund their projects through internal funds), I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1234] was not of the specified subclass [FundingOrganisation] : loaded object was of wrong class class ResearchInstitution
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:371)
[...]
```

I found a few issues (like [this one](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911#icft=HHH-6911)) where the use of a discriminator Column was the problem, which is not my case as a Discriminator column could not reflect the fact that the base Entity can have both subtype roles.

Question is: is there any way to represent my model with JPA inheritance? Is there a missing annotation I could use to hint Hibernate to load a different type of subclass the second time it tries to materialize the same base entity for a project?
I have not found any documentation explicitely stating that subtypes should be exclusive in a Joined Inheritance scenario.

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance. It is impossible to have a class that extends two objects. Seeing as Java does not support this, neither does JPA

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. This is a classic case of not seeing the forest for the trees... Any ideas as how I could model this efficiently without repeating data or using different Ids for the 3 entities?

Comment: One idea: create a separate class `OrganisationFacet` and have subclasses for research and funding. Then create a 1-to-many association from `Organisation` to `OrganisationFacet`